# Where does this force skill bonus come from?

Tags: star-wars-d20

I’m taking like 10 years of dirt of an old PC from Star Wars d20 and found that my PC has a bonus to all force skills. This bonus is based on the jedi guardian level * 1/3 plus the jedi master level * 2/3.

I cannot find any rules that explain these bonuses. What feature grants this bonus and what book does it originate from?

The PC was create using the Original and revised editions releases of the WOTC Starwars.

Comment: Are you asking where that bonus is coming from, or what the bonus ends up doing? Otherwise I don't understand what  "I cannot find any rules that apply to that" is going at (but I'm personally unfamiliar with the system, so I may be missing something).

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long search i finally found it.

They come from the optional Rule "Force Aptitude", you can found it on the "Revenge of the Sith Collection" (it is like a Web Enhancement that was release after the movie).

[ROTS COLLECTION ON WOTC SITE](https://web.archive.org/web/20090601200018/http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=starwars/article/ROTScollection)